# HTTP Live Streaming MPEG TS segment

Tags: http, ffmpeg, live-streaming, mpeg, transport-stream

I'm using FFMPEG and a free segmenter (Carson Mcdonald's) to produce my ts segments which i later save to a web server and play with Quicktime by playing the .m3u8

If I have segments 1,2,3,4 and another stream with segments 1,2,3,4 and would like to interleave them what should I do. If i do as follows: 1,2, other stream's 3, 4 It works fine. However, If i want to do as follows: 1,2, other stream's 4, 4 it doesn't work.

In other words the segment to be added must have the same number as the one I'm replacing. Why is that? Does it have to do with PCR? I would like to be able to interleave any segment anywhere.. How can I do that?

Thank you,

The M3U8 file is

```
#EXTM3U 
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10 
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:21 
#EXTINF:10, sample_ep_386k-00021.ts 
#EXTINF:10, media_2.ts 
#EXTINF:10, sample_ep_386k-00023.ts
```

Comment: Could you post the M3U8 file?

Comment: As an experiment, if you cat the files together, e.g. 'cat 1 2 other4 4 > test.ts', can you play that video back in VLC?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it doesn't work"?  What behaviour do you see?

Comment: @TheJuice I mean it plays sample_ep_386k-00021 then when it goes to the segment of the other stream (media_2) it freezes, then jumps and goes to the segment after that (sample.. 23)... so it doesn't even play it. But IF media_2 was actually segment 22 in the other stream.. it plays fine!

Comment: @TheJuice When I concatenate the files as you suggested, they play normally with VLC... I feel the problem is when i play them with the playlist file on the spot without concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the .M3U8 playlist (index) file to point to the two 4 files?  I assume they are at distinct locations on the server.

Comment: Yes I modified it to include locations of new segments. At the moment I'm keeping them at the same location for simplicity. This is the playlist file:     `#EXTM3U
    #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:21
#EXTINF:10,
sample_ep_386k-00021.ts
#EXTINF:10,
media_2.ts
#EXTINF:10,
sample_ep_386k-00023.ts`  where media_2 is from the other stream, segment number 2.

Comment: Just to be clear if media_2 was even sample_ep_386k-00003 or any segment in the same stream but a different segment number.. it also doesn't work.

Comment: I found a way around my original problem. Thank you.

Comment: @tommychheng I'm sorry I don't quite remember because it was a while back.. but I believe that instead of editing the current playlist file, I used to point to another one with the segments I want to interleave, and then point back to this one when it's done...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the common problem faced by many in SO.

See my answer here: [MPEG-TS Segments HTTP Live Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635666/mpeg-ts-segments-http-live-streaming/8644496#8644496)

things to check out :

o PCR (timestamp) discontinuity
o Matching framerate
o file format
o number and type of tracks
o encoding parameters
o encoding sequence